# Redirecting execution result into a file (Node.js app)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, stdout, snap

I'm trying to run a js file containing just one simple line:

```
\\file.js
console.log("a");
```

And redirect it into a txt file, like this:

```
node file.js > txt
```

File gets created but empty. If I execute the file without redirecting stdout, it prints correctly into the console.

If I execute anything else, such as:

`echo "a" > txt`

It also works.

This reproduces only on one Ubuntu 20.04 instance, hosted by Njal.la. Node installed using snap, v 16.15.1.